# Get the maximum decimal number

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex

```
Regex.Match(result, @"\b(?<=Pay Rate)(\D*)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)");
```

This works great but it only works when there's only 1 rate. It only grabs the first one, which is great because when the Pay Rate only has 1 rate this perfectly works. However, there's a possibility that the Pay Rate can have multiple rates. For example,

Pay Rate: 12.12% 13.13% 14.14% 15.15% (I don't know, it can go on and on and on).
So when there is more than 1 rate, I want to just get the highest rate (always 2 decimal places). And when there's only one, just print the first one.

Comment: are you getting this "12.12% 13.13% 14.14% 15.15% " as string ?

Comment: Amit Yes, I'm getting it as string 
anubhava match the highest decimal. So in  that case it would be 15.15%

Comment: Regex cannot get max value. You will have to store all numbers in a list and get max value inside the code

Comment: Ok, I was just curious. Just trying to find a better way to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve by using lambda expressions

```
var payRate = "12.12% 13.13% 14.14% 15.15% 10.10%";
var splitPayRate = payRate.Split(new char[] {' '});

var maxPayRate = splitPayRate.Select(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.Replace("%",""))).ToList().OrderByDescending(x=>x).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: 1. Calling `Replace` method everytime is redundant. 2.`ToList()` is not required. 3. Alternate way for `OrderByDescending().Take().FirstOrDefault()` is  only one method i.e `.Max()`.

This will reduce processing of your LINQ solution drastically. Kindly check my solution

Comment: You are doing lot of unnecessary operations  in your solution

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar replace function from string or replace from each element of array, using max of order by descending, is there any difference for the compiler? In all the cases compiler will work in same way.  Please correct me if it wrong.

Comment: I think honestly when you Split, the last element should be the highest value. So I think splitPayRate.Last(); will honestly do the job.

Comment: @davis we can not assume this that last will always be max.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how you guys got the "10.10%" at the end. It just goes up.

Comment: I never said that. The last will be always highest because the numbers are always in the order.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar And in case of empty string max will throw error. But FirstOrDefault() will never throw error instead it will return 0.

Comment: But this definitely gave me some ideas. I really appreciate it Amit. I will select your answer! Thank you again.

Comment: @davis If the max rate is _always_ the last one, you can simply use `Regex.Match(input, @"\bPay Rate:(?:\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%)+").Groups[1].Value`. I've added that to my answer below.

Comment: @AmitVerma, Kindly check ShareLab url: https://sharplab.io/#gist:d2a81edf8d9889bb7d735f4beb67a9c9
Here IL for your query. Its completely up to you how to write a Linq. Happy coding 

Comment: @AmitVerma, `replace function from string or replace from each element of array` There is a BIG difference when there are 1 million records in a single string

Answer (score 1):

You may use repeated capturing groups for this, parse the number found in each group capture, and then get the max rate. Because we'll be using a capturing group anyway, I would drop the Lookarounds. Something like this should work:

```
string input = "Pay Rate: 12.12% 13.13% 14.14% 15.15%";
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"\bPay Rate:(?:\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%)+");
if (match.Success)
{
    var rate = match.Groups[1]
        .Captures.OfType<Capture>()
        .Select(c => decimal.Parse(c.Value))
        .Max();
    Console.WriteLine(rate); // 15.15
}
```

If you're certain that the max rate is always the last one, you could simply use:

```
Regex.Match(input, @"\bPay Rate:(?:\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%)+").Groups[1].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Max()` from Linq,

```
var input = "12.12% 13.13% 14.14% 15.15% 10.10%";
var result =  input.Replace("%","") //Remove all % from input string in one go
                .Split(" ") //Split by space
                .Select(decimal.Parse) //Convert IEnumerable of string to IEnumerable of float
                .Max(); //Get Max element from given list
```

[POC: .net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gd0iUJ)